# Tag Removal Request: cram-md5

Tags: support, retag-request

[cram-md5](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/cram-md5) was a worthless tag with 1 question. It is now a worthless tag with 0 questions.

Please remove this tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Empty tags will be purged automatically overnight.

Comment: I had wondered. Now I know.